# How does an ASP.NET session expire when the browser is closed?

Tags: asp.net

As in the title, I wonder how a session expires when the client's browser is closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The session lives on the server. It expires when the browser is closed long enough or isn't used long enough or when a new request arrives that either doesn't contain the cookie, or the cookie refers to a sessionid that's too far in the past (default timeout is 20 minutes).

When there's no connection, the session is removed from memory at an undetermined moment in time, or when you programmatically call `.Abandon` on the session.

When a session is not available or a session has been cleared because it had timed out, a new session object will be created. When this is the result of a browser request, the `Session_End` event will trigger in the global.asax file.

Note: the actual way a session is timed out and cleared depends. I.e., inproc sessions will be destroyed and trigger a `Session_Timeout`. Out-of-proc sessions do not, and will be destroyed in a state server or an SQL server. In the latter case, a stored procedure is called regularly to clean up. The stored procedure is only called when there's activity on the server, which means that sessions can live longer than 20 minutes in (database) memory, but will be destroyed on next access.

Comment: From where and how Session_Timeout event will be triggerd when browser is closed?

Comment: @Bala: It will not be triggered when the browser is closed, HTTP is stateless. But the session will be cleared at some time. I'll update my post with a link as to why this is the way it is.

Comment: @Bala: actually, I've just rewritten my answer to remove ambiguities and vagueness (I hope), but do ask if something is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

As defined on the web server (e.g. IIS).  The typical default is around 20 mins after the last access (i.e. web request for that session).  At this point the session is cleared, so apps need to use either cookies or some server-side state to work out who someone is for return visits to make the experience seamless.

Comment: The typical default is 20 minutes ;-)

Comment: Ooops - thanks.  Updated.  (I was thinking of ADO.NET command timeouts...)

Comment: How the session is cleared? any event will be triggered or it is a browser properties?

Comment: @Bala: see my answer for an answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

The browsers temporary cookies are deleted and the server kills the session data after a predetermined amount of time since last access.

Comment: Cookies have their own expiry details, separate from the session on the web server.

Comment: Yes and No cookies used to track sessions are not given an expiration date/time and expire as soon as the browser is closed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Answer (score 1):

It does and doesn't. It lives on on the server until it times out (usually 20 minutes). But since it's kept alive in the browser using a session cookie, that expires as the browser is closed, the user will not be able to reconnect to that session again.